# Cucumber feature cannot detect the relative path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, log4j, cucumber

I have created a project in eclipse Kepler using cucumber and junit runner. 
Also I am using log4j.properties file placed under config folder in my project. Log4j property configuration is defined as below in Base class.

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("config/log4j.properties");
```

**Profile.feature**

```
Feature: This is a profile feature
  @Testing
  Scenario: this is the first scenario for Profile page
  Given I open Naukri app
  When I tap on "Profile Image"
  Then The toolbar shows "User Profile"
```

**RunnerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format = { "pretty", "html:target/html/", "json:target/json/output.json"},  
        features = "src/test/features",
        glue = "com.stepsdefination",
        tags = {"@Testing"}
        )
public class RunnerTest {

}
```

Now When i run the Profile.feature file in eclipse it shows -

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: config\log4j.properties (The system
>   cannot find the path specified)

But when I directly run the RunnerTest.java file then it works perfect.

Why my feature file is not taking the relative path. It work when I hard code the file location like 'D:\Project\Workspace\DemoCucumer\config\log4j.properties'. 
It not possible to change the file path every-time when location is changed.

Project Structure:

```
DemoCucumber
>src\main\java
>src\test\java
>config > log4j.properties
```

I have installed and downloaded all plugin related to cucumber in eclipse.

Comment: What is your path relative to? How do you know?

Comment: Relative I mean I have kept in project itself and not give the complete path like ''D:\Project\Workspace\DemoCucumer\config\log4j.properties''. Added project structure in question description

Comment: And in your `PropertyConfigurator.configure(...)` statement, how did you indicate that?

Comment: 'config/log4j.properties' is my file path. This is the way we indicate in java. Right?

Comment: You **cannot** guarantee the starting position!!! Do not use relative paths!!! Build it into your .jar and retrieve it as a resource.

Comment: But this is working fine when running RunTest.java. Its creating problem when running cucumber feature file.

Comment: Because by *coincidence*, you managed to get the correct starting directory relative to your properties file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your configuration file as a resource:

If your project is a Maven project, you need to have a directory called `src/main/resources` and move the entire "config" directory in there.

In Eclipse, right-click on the `resources` directory, and select Build Path > Use as Source Folder. The decorator on the folder icon will change!

In your code, to retrieve the file, you need something like:

```
URL res = getClass().getResource("/config/log4j.properties");
Assert.assertNotNull("Your resources are not configured correctly!", res);
File f = new File(res.getFile());
PropertyConfigurator.configure(f.getCanonicalPath());
```

Comment: I am getting nullpointerexception at File f = new File(res.getFile());

Comment: You did not add the config directory as a source folder correctly.

Comment: Yes I did added the config folder and icon appearance changed to source folder.

Comment: Wait ... I just noticed your "Project Structure" comment. Are you using Maven?

Comment: Updated my answer for Maven!

Comment: Even after moving my config in src/main/resources or src/test/resoureces, I am getting nullpointerexception @File f = new File(res.getFile());. When cucumber feature  file. Is it because we have to use url like 'http://stackoverflow.com' ?

Comment: I do not know anything about cucumber. Can you try this in a clean project, only Eclipse + Maven + JUnit?

Comment: /config/log4j.properties is working correct in junit, maven, eclipse but creating problem when running feature file. This is my main concern how to run using cucumber feature file.

Comment: I do not know anything about cucumber. Sorry.